# How to pass the array in the postman

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have created the modal class in the DRF reference to ManytoMany. When I am trying to pass the array through the PostMan it's throwing an error as `"Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str."` But when I am passing directly through Web in 'as_view()' It's successfully inserting in the database. My modal class is :

```
class PackageComponent(models.Model):
    pkg_code = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    comp_code = models.ManyToManyField(
        'core.SensorDevice'
    )
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

So, When I am passing the array in comp code through PostMan in component code as [1,2]. I am getting the error. So my question is how can I pass the array? Any suggestions are most welcome. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you meant "model" instead of "modal" ?

Answer (score 0):

If you pass multiple values under the same key they will get interpreted as a list in Django. So in Postman you would use e.g. form-data as `comp_code=1&comp_code=2&comp_code=3`.
You can read the data then as `request.data.getlist('comp_code') # [1, 2, 3]`.